Faulty listing code display using language=LaTeX
The two snapshots correspond to (A) with and (B) without the specified option for \newtcblisting. The code display is faulty in (A) and satisfactory in (B). How can I rectify this while keeping the option?
tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting{texl}{
  listing options={language={[LaTeX]TeX}}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{texl}
I use \LaTeX for editing: Voluptate atque ipsa minima qui esse ut at. Minima nulla accusamus quos. Quidem consectetur consequatur ullam id aut quia. Reiciendis pariatur in debitis voluptas quis ad. Facilis quia a consequuntur debitis.
\end{texl}

\end{document}

Also see:

listings man




By default, tcolorbox uses style=tcblatex as option for listings. You could add it to your options:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting{texl}{
  listing options={language={[LaTeX]TeX},style=tcblatex}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{texl}
I use \LaTeX\ for editing: Voluptate atque ipsa minima qui esse ut at. Minima nulla accusamus quos. Quidem consectetur consequatur ullam id aut quia. Reiciendis pariatur in debitis voluptas quis ad. Facilis quia a consequuntur debitis.
\end{texl}

\end{document}


Alternatively, you could replicate the main features like this:

the breaklines option will allow line breaks

use the basicstyle option to adjust font and size as you like



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting{texl}{
  listing options={language={[LaTeX]TeX},breaklines,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{texl}
I use \LaTeX\ for editing: Voluptate atque ipsa minima qui esse ut at. Minima nulla accusamus quos. Quidem consectetur consequatur ullam id aut quia. Reiciendis pariatur in debitis voluptas quis ad. Facilis quia a consequuntur debitis.
\end{texl}

\end{document}



